# Different Session SqlServer and ConnectionString(data which contain main database)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, session-state

I am building a multi tenant site.
Currently I am using `mode="InProc"` to store my sessionstate; but now planing to switch to sqlserver sessionstate.

My Question Is;

Can I maintain different database for sql sessionstate separated from my current database?

What will be the standard practice for multi tenant architecture with separate database for each client?

I mean

```
     <connectionStrings>
          // Connectionstring for my client data; suppose "DatabaseClient"
     </connectionStrings>
//---------------------
    // Here connection for sql session dataabse; suppose "DatabaseSession"
    <sessionState 
                mode="SQLServer" 
                sqlConnectionString="server=127.0.0.1;uid=<user id>;pwd=<password>;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Store two connection string in connectionstrings section in config. One for business database and one for session storage database.if membership implement is custom for each tenant (custom profiles , roles ,password police's..etc )  the complexity may high in single session db  else you are in correct way